# Are there any more Asgardians?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the opening scenes of *Infinity War*, Thanos and the Black Order

> have killed basically everyone aboard the Asgardian ship, which amounts to everyone who escaped the destruction of Asgard itself at the end of *Thor: Ragnarok*.  After this, Thanos destroys the whole ship using the Power Stone.  The end result is that Thor is picked up as the only survivor, by the Guardians of the Galaxy.

Of course, we learned during *Thor: Ragnarok* that not all Asgardians are necessarily on Asgard (Valkyrie was living on Sakaar, after all).

Do we have any indication that there are any other such Asgardians anywhere else in the MCU at the current time, or is Thor now officially (or at least "as far as we know") the last of the Asgardian race?  I'd prefer an official confirmation if one exists anywhere.

Comment: In the film after being rescued, Thor does say that Thanos 'wiped out half my people' which seems to indicate at least half of the survivors of Asgard's destruction have survived somehow or somewhere.

Comment: He does say that, but I wasn't sure if he was entirely aware of everything at that point, and they only had the one ship - which was destroyed.  I suppose Thanos may have allowed half the ship's population onto escape pods or the like?

Comment: It's quite possible, given that leaving half the population alive is kind of Thanos' whole thing. I didn't think of that at the time.

Comment: Kind of a jerk move considering so much of their population had already just been wiped out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing official, but two Asgardians that are unaccounted for are Lady Sif, who didn't appear in either *Thor: Ragnarok* or *Avengers: Infinity War*, and Valkyrie, who was weirdly absent at the beginning of *Infinity War*, even though she was present at the end of *Ragnarok* (along with Korg).

[According to Jamie Alexander](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1718769/why-lady-sif-didnt-appear-in-thor-ragnarok-according-to-jamie-alexander) (the actress who plays Sif), it was a scheduling conflict with her show (*Blindspot*) that kept her out of *Ragnarok*. If Marvel can work that out, I'd say there's still a chance for her to show up again in the MCU.

---

Since this question was originally asked, we've seen Valkyrie and many other Asgardians living on Earth in *Avengers: Endgame*. Half of the Asgardians that survived the destruction of Asgard in *Thor: Ragnarok* escaped from Thanos and made their way to Midgard (Earth).

We also saw Lady Sif show up in *Loki*, but it wasn't clear (to me) when in time this version of Sif was from.

Comment: I forgot about Sif.  Definitely a chance - perhaps an in-universe explanation could be that she was off Asgard on some mission or other for Loki-as-Odin and so avoided all the destruction of Ragnarok and Infinity War...

Comment: The last we saw Sif was in Agents of Shield. She was escorting a Kree to his home planet. Kevin Feige mentioned that she was probably banished from Asgard by Loki-as-Odin because she might discover who he is.

Answer (score 27):

## Half of the Asgardians still live.

Later in the movie, Thor describes Thanos and claims

> Thanos already has the Power Stone
> because he stole it last week,
> when he decimated Xandar.
> He stole the Space Stone from me. When he destroyed my ship and
> **slaughtered half my people**.

Not all my people, just half.

[Joe Russo](https://io9.gizmodo.com/joe-russo-gave-the-infinity-war-answers-youve-been-wait-1825776831) commented, and also reported in [ComicBook](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/01/avengers-infinity-war-valkyrie-asgardian-fate/):

> The director did not say how, but he did say a portion of the Asgardians also survived. Russo said escape pods ferried those survivors away from the battle, giving the Asgardian race the chance to escape extinction.

So yes, there are still Asgardians out there.

---

Infinity War and Endgame update: Five years after the snap, we see Valkyrie and many Asgardians in the New Asgard. Banner even tells Rocket:

> Hey, have a little compassion, pal. First, they've lost Asgard, then half the people. They're probably just happy they have a home.

Best confirmation we can have.

Comment: Note that ComicBook's article is sourced from a [not-very-well-verified reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8g10pg/joe_russo_came_and_had_a_qa_at_our_high_school/dy83jb5/) rather than a recorded interview. I would take this claim with a grain of salt until we see some more reporting.

Comment: The other half had already been slaughtered by Hela

Comment: Who's Ratchet?  Do you mean Rocket?

Comment: @Dave Oops, yeah. Fixed

Answer (score 8):

Now that *Avengers: Endgame* is out, we know that some Asgardians survived indeed,

> and settled "New Asgard" in Tønsberg, Norway, with Thor as their leader. These Asgardians include Valkyrie, Korg and Miek (Thor's fellow gladiators from *Ragnarok*). It's unclear how many people were there, but New Asgard overall looked the size of a small fishing city. It's also unclear how they went from the wrecked spaceship in outer space to Earth.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

Joe Russo has now confirmed that Asgardians, including Valkyrie survived.

> There certainly were survivors — Thor does say to the Guardians that [Thanos] slaughtered half his people [but] prior to the start of that scene escape ships were deployed for Asgardians — including Valkyrie.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://io9.gizmodo.com/joe-russo-gave-the-infinity-war-answers-youve-been-wait-1825776831)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There is also another instance of an Asgardian on Earth in the MCU through the ABC TV show Agents of Shield. Prof. Elliot Randolf, was confirmed to be Asgardian at 24:30 of Season 1 Episode 8 of Agents of Shield. (I just watched part of the episode to confirm). He lived permanently on Earth for an unknown amount of time. (Thousands of years).

This is just to provide another example of an Asgardian off of Asgard to support the theory that there may be more on other/unknown planets.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are a few who visit Earth during the show, including Lady Sif and Lorelei, although I believe they both return to Asgard at the end of their respective shows - could you be talking about Elliot Randolph, who was posing as a human professor of Norse Mythology?

Comment: Dave, thanks for the help and input. See above to confirm. Funny enough, it was the episode that aired directly after the release of Thor: The Dark World.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likely that only a few of those rescued by Loki, Korg, and company (from the battle on the Rainbow Bridge) may have survived, probably escaping aboard Grandmaster Goldblum's pleasure craft (or escape pods we never saw) while the rest were killed. But it seems improbable they were the only ones.

First, Asgard ruled... er, maintained peace in a benevolent manner... over Nine Realms. It wouldn't make sense they did it from a single world, especially a large, flat-earth discworld asteroid with its atmosphere. They would have had to have a bunch of outposts and fleets of space-faring warships to supplement the Bifrost.

Mind you, Loki kind of let everything go to hell when he was pretending to be Odin, and when word spreads about what Hela did, and then Thanos (and what perfect timing that was, almost like he arranged it), those outposts and fleets are not going to be able to help Thor and the others because they will be very busy just trying to survive.

Second, it's also possible that not all of the survivors from the Asgard capital tried to escape using the Bifrost. Heimdall may have sent some to escape by other means. Space vessels may have been one way, but Hela would have locked them down after her return. The other way was revealed in Dark World when Heimdall said "There are other ways off Asgard, known only to a few", and we assumed only Loki knew of these. Heimdall and Odin probably did too, but they wouldn't be sharing that knowledge.

These other 'gateways' to other places could have been used by survivors, with the rest being either cut off by Hela's forces or deliberately trying to use the Bifrost to distract her while the rest used the other ways. This allows Thor's ship to get blown up in Infinity War in a manner that leaves no survivors but doesn't undermine New Asgard on Earth where any other survivors from fallen outposts can rally too.